# How do I set up the test data and the test cases in a single python script

Tags: python, unit-testing, ddt

I am writing a unit test and trying to set up the test data to use for the test cases in the same python script.

However, When I run the script, it does create the test data, but prints an error message that the data do not exist, leading to the test failure. It's only when I run the script again that the test succeeds.

Below is a simplified script that I wrote to figure out what's going on.

```py
import unittest
from ddt import ddt, file_data
import pandas

@ddt
class TestWhatever(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.setup_test_data()
        print("setUpClass is running")

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print("tearDownClass is running")

    @classmethod
    def setup_test_data(cls):
        data = pandas.DataFrame({'msg':["testing"]})
        data = data.transpose()
        with open("practice_test.json", "w") as file:
           file.write(data.to_json())
        print("setup_test_data is running")

    @file_data("practice_test.json")
    def test_whatever_possible(self, msg):
        print("test_whatever_possible is running :", msg)
        self.assertEqual('q', 'q')

    def test_whatever_impossible(self):
        print("test_whatever_impossible is running")
        self.assertEqual('n', 'n')
```

When I run the script above, it prints :

```
setup_test_data is running
setUpClass is running
test_whatever_impossible is running
.EtearDownClass is running

======================================================================
ERROR: test_whatever_possible_00001_error (main.TestWhatever)
Error!
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ddt.py", line 145, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ddt.py", line 187, in func
    raise ValueError(message % file_attr)
ValueError: practice_test.json does not exist

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.006s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Then on the second run :

```
setup_test_data is running
setUpClass is running
test_whatever_impossible is running
.test_whatever_possible is running : testing
.tearDownClass is running

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.005s

OK
```

I'm pretty much lost at this point...
Does anyone have a clue on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you could write your own decorator to create the data file e.g.

```py
def create_data(name):
    def decorator(fn):
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            data = pandas.DataFrame({"msg": ["testing"]})
            data = data.transpose()
            with open(name, "w") as file:
                file.write(data.to_json())
            res = fn(*args, **kwargs)
            os.unlink(name)
            return res
        return decorated
    return decorator
```

and then stack this for your test (and remove the `setup_test_data` step):

```py
@ddt
class TestWhatever(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print("setUpClass is running")

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print("tearDownClass is running")

    @create_data("practice_test.json")
    @file_data("practice_test.json")
    def test_whatever_possible(self):
        print("test_whatever_possible is running :")
        self.assertEqual("q", "q")
```

#### Update: Jan 31st

The following example preserves the ddt behaviour of passing the parameter value into the test function:

```py
import json
import unittest
from ddt import ddt, FILE_ATTR


def create_file_data(value, data):
    def wrapper(func):
        with open(value, "w") as file:
            file.write(json.dumps(data))
        # this is what the file_data decorator does
        setattr(func, FILE_ATTR, value)
        return func

    return wrapper


@ddt
class TestWhatever(unittest.TestCase):
    @create_file_data("practice_test.json", {"msg": ["testing"]})
    def test_file_data(self, msg):
        print("test_file_data msg:", msg)


unittest.main()
```

When this is run the output is:

```
test_file_data msg: ['testing']
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s
```

Using the two examples above you should be able to derive an appropriate solution for your problem.

Comment: The workaround did create a json file for the test method, but the data('msg') inside the file is not passed into test_whatever_possible anymore.

Would there be a workaround on this as well?

Comment: @jsy I've added another example to my answer

Comment: @jsy has the additional example helped you?

Comment: Yes. Now I am looking into the source code of ddt library to modify your example to my needs. :)

Comment: @jsy Can you accept this as an answer then, as it may help others out when searching for similar. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All Python code is executable. When a class body gets loaded, the statements in it are executed. A decorated function creates the function with the coffee inside the `def`, assigns it to the name (e.g. `test_whatever_possible`) in the temporary class namespace, and then replaces it with the result of calling the decorator.

The reason this is important is that the decorator is called when the class is loaded, not when the tests are run. The decorator [`file_data`](https://ddt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#ddt.file_data) checks that the file exists right then and there (indirectly), since it has to replace your test function with one that calls your test with the values in the file.

Your second run passed because the first run had created the test file. I would recommend filling an issue on GitHub. Either `file_data` needs to delay opening the file, or the unexpected behavior needs to be documented somewhere clearly.

You can see exactly where this magic happens in the [source code](https://github.com/datadriventests/ddt/blob/5985839d4dd600c41279132318bc440f4963c032/ddt.py).[`file_data`](https://github.com/datadriventests/ddt/blob/5985839d4dd600c41279132318bc440f4963c032/ddt.py#L102) merely flags your test function for further processing. [`process_file_data`](https://github.com/datadriventests/ddt/blob/5985839d4dd600c41279132318bc440f4963c032/ddt.py#L191) then checks if the file can be used to expand the actual tests, or creates a replacement that just raises the error you see.